# How to convert date format from mm.dd.yy to month name dd, yyyy?

Tags: vbscript, date-formatting

I have an Excel file exported from SAP system with date that has a format of `mm.dd.yy` (example: `08.03.17`) however, I need to import the Excel file to another system that uses a VBScript and it only accepts a date format of `month name dd, yyyy` (example: `Aug. 03, 2017`).

I kept on searching for similar question but failed to find any solution. Please help.
I do not have much knowledge with VBScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO is not a place where other people write code for you. We usually don't answer questions when the answer would entail writing the entire script for you. I'll give you some pointers, though:

- Start with [splitting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5) your date string:

  ```
  str = "08.03.17"
  arr = Split(str, ".")
  ```
- Determine the (short) [month name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58f13257) from the month fragment:

  ```
  m = MonthName(arr(0), True)
  ```
- Change the year to a full year by [prepending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w00s0c3k) it with the string "20":

  ```
  y = "20" & arr(2)
  ```

  You'll need additional logic if your date values could predate the year 2000.
- Rebuild the date string from the fragments:

  ```
  WScript.Echo m & ". " & arr(1) & ", " & y
  ```